# Is there any way to access the MySQL's GEOMETRY type with EclipseLink?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, spatial

Good evening,
like the title is saying, i'm trying to access a MySQL database table which has an GEOMETRY field within over EclipseLink. I know this is possible with Hibernate and also EclipseLink is able to access SDO_Geometry fields in Oracle databases. But i wonder is there is any solution for EclipseLink and MySQL.
Thanks in advance.